# Gradient font awesome IN REACT

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome, linear-gradients

Adding gradient color to font awesome icon seems easy generally, just apply the following css:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#9c47fc, #356ad2);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

But for some reason I cannot make it happen in React. my jsx is:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon className="audio-icon" icon="step-backward" />
```

And the css:

```
.audio-icon {
  font-size: 20rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#9c47fc, #356ad2);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

The gradient doesn't apply. if I use !important:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#9c47fc, #356ad2) !important;
```

It applies to the background, but I cannot add !important to the webkit-background-clip and webkit-text-fill-color

Also, trying to to select the psuedo element .audio-icon::before doesn't do anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: remove webit keep it only `linear-gradient()`

Comment: Hey Termani, tried it, doesn't work

Comment: I meant you no more need the webkit with gradient, you can use the above one and you should have the same result (either if it works or not)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it's a problem with font aswesome npm for react, but anyhow the work around is to just do it the old way:
1. Add the cdn link to index.html
2. use the normal html syntax:

```
<i className="fas fa-step-backward audio-icon"></i>
```

If someone happens to know how to apply it with the npm package for React I would appreciate it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="step-backward" style={{background:"-webkit-linear-gradient(#9c47fc, #356ad2)"}} />
```

(without !important)

or using plain "linear-gradient"

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="step-backward" style={{background:"linear-gradient(#9c47fc, #356ad2)"}} />
```